# Permission to activate an Iteration in TFS 2013

Tags: permissions

I want to give permission for a specific user in my TFS project to do the following.

1. Create Iterations
2. Edit the Iterations
3. Activate the Iteration (In simpler words, 'tick' the Iterations so that they can be seen by others in the team)

MSDN says that

> To create or modify areas or iterations, you must either be a member of the Project Administrators group, or your Create and order child nodes, Delete this node, and Edit this node permissions must be set to Allow for the area or iteration node that you want to modify. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Work/customize/modify-areas-iterations)

I do not want to give **Project Administrator** permissions to this specific user.

Hence I gave the following permissions to him in the Parent Iteration.

[permissions - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/holLE.png)

When logged in as the specific user, TFS says that

> You do not have sufficient permissions to configure iterations for this team. You must either be a team administrator or a project administrator.

However, the User can do the following.

1. Create Child Nodes
2. Edit the Start/End Dates of existing/new iterations

My question is:

- Is there any other way to give a user the permission to 'tick' an iteration without giving him 'Edit collection level permission' or 'project admin permission'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new TFS group under your team project. Then, grant that group "Edit Project Level Information" permissions. This will allow the user to check the tick box to make the iteration show up in the backlog task board.

What I did was create a "[TEAM PROJECT]\Project Managers" TFS group, I granted that group all permissions on the root node of both the Areas and Iterations. And I also granted that group "Edit Project Level Information." My user was then able to manage areas and iterations - including the "ticking" to activate the iteration.